# Creating filtering by 'Created_at' and/or presence of data in multiple columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, filter

Big newbie here. Started rails recently. I've been searching and I'm stuck on forward progress where I've reached filtering.

Currently on my index page, I'm showing all orders created. Customers (first_name, last_name) pay by 'cash', 'credit', or 'check' (shown in decimal(8,2)). I would like to create a filter where manager can click on a DATE , filter any payment type (cash, credit or check), for reconciliation purposes.

I have searched many and confused as to what method to use. My best guess is that I have to use some sort of 'scoped' methodology? If you can point me in the right direction, I'd like to solve it myself. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi and Welcome to Stack Overflow. So... what happened when you tried to make a scope? We aren't going to write your code for you - but if you have a go, and get stuck, we'll help you get past the bugs. So: have a go at it yourself, and come back to us if it's not working the way you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scopes are great in ruby.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/scope

if you want to filter by a certain date. Say you want everything that is supposed to happen after today you do the following. Put a scope definition like this in the model you want to scope. Lets call it Mimodel

```
scope :post_dated, where("created_at > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
```

That is a dumb example but an example nonetheless. If you want to filter by after given date you can use lambdas

```
scope :post_dated, lambda { |date| where("DATE(created_at) > ?" date) }
```

Then you call them wherever by calling Mimodel.post_dated for the first example and you'll get all Mimodel objects that occurred after today. For the second example you call Mimodel(Date.today) for the same affect or Mimodel((Time.now-30.days)) for 30 days ago.

Your specific problem I cannot see so I cannot help with that but scopes help you define various queries into single code-first calls.